# Is it legal to modify the result of std::string::op[]?

Tags: c++, string, std

Consider the following from C++11:

> `[C++11: 21.4.5]:` **`basic_string` element access                           [string.access]**
>
> ```
> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
> reference       operator[](size_type pos);
> ```
>
> <sup>1</sup>     *Requires:* `pos <= size()`.
>
> <sup>2</sup>     *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.
>
> <sup>3</sup>     *Throws:* Nothing.
>
> <sup>4</sup>     *Complexity:* constant time.

This means either:

- The referenced value in the `pos == size()` case shall not be modified, or
- In *any* case, the referenced value returned by `op[]` shall not be modified, even for the non-`const` overload.

The second scenario seems completely ridiculous, but I think it's what the wording most strongly implies.

**Can we modify what we get from `std::string::op[]`, or not?** And is this not rather ambiguous wording?

Comment: Looks like you can...but shouldn't. XD
Wait, isn't the answer in the definition of SHOULD?

Comment: @Klaim: It's about what it is that "the referenced value shall not be modified" is talking about.

Comment: I wonder how this compares to `vector::op[]`... interesting, I can't find anything where they talk about this...

Comment: @Nim: Interestingly, Table 101 calls `basic_string` a "container". News to me.

Comment: @Nim: Sequence containers do not appear to have this ambiguity, and I'd assume that this is because it does not have that dereferenceable sentinel value, and thus that the first scenario is correct. But it's by no means certain.

Comment: A very good question, I was under the impression that this was now allowed in c++11 but it's clear that there are some grounds to doubt it...

Comment: Reading and re-reading, I would agree with @rodrigo and his comment below, you must not modify the reference in the case where `pos >= size`, otherwise, there is no specific restriction (so I guess implementation defined).

Comment: @Nim: If I get a non-`const` ref back and there's no restriction mentioned, then it had better not be implementation-defined as to whether I may modify the object through that ref.

Comment: I'd say the semicolon means that the sentence "the referenced value shall not be modified" applies in general, not just when `pos == size()`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Right, in terms of English that is implied, but in terms of common sense (and deductions from elsewhere in the document) it cannot be the case, surely.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: It's really a shame that they chose to make it so ambiguous. Surely another half-sentence to explain what they mean wouldn't have hurt! Anyway, I'm tempted to stick with the immutable assumption simply because `data()` returns a const pointer. `vector` is no different from `string` in terms of allocation, yet `vector::data()` returns a mutable pointer, so that's making me cautious.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think `data` is a red-herring and has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Actually, I've had a few other folks look purely at the language, and from an English language (not my first either), perspective, the `;` forces the latter condition to apply to the whole sentence, basically as it stands, *the reference value shall **not** be modified*.

Comment: I think that if on both cases the reference should not be modified, both should have returned a `const_reference`.

Comment: @Nim: I'm a bit of an English language expert (and it _is_ my first language) and, yes, that's the implication when considering the grammar alone. But that's the point of this question.

Comment: FWIW, assuming we take the sensible meaning I would write it, "`*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`; that object shall not be modified."

Comment: I'm told the wording is being fixed as a result of this question. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quote means that you cannot modify the return of `operator[]( size() )`, even if the value is well defined. That is, you must not modify the NUL terminator in the string even through the non-const overload.

This is basically your first option: i.e. `pos >= size()`, but because of the requirement `pos <= size()` the only possible value for that condition is `pos == size()`.

The actual English description of the clause can be ambiguous (at least to me), but Appendix C, and in particular C.2.11 deals with changes in semantics in the string library, and there is no mention to this change --that would break user code. In C++03 the *"referenced value shall not be modified"* bit is not present and there is no ambiguity. The lack of mention in C.2.11 is not normative, but can be used as a hint that when they wrote the standard there was no intention on changing this particular behavior.

Comment: That's the first possibility I mentioned (and yeah I know that it can be condensed to `pos == size()`), but can you be _sure_ that that is what it means?

Comment: If `operator[]` did not allow you to modify the contents even in the non-const overload, that would be a (non-sensical) break in the semantics from C++03, and it would be listed in the *C Compatibility* appendix of the standard. I am not a native English speaker, but common sense dictates this interpretation.

Comment: Yes, it effectively means: if pos==size() then it returns a reference to a charT() that shall not be modified. I think that the comma and the semicolon are switched, because in English, `;` has more precedence than ','.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I know; I said that the second possibility would be ridiculous. You're just repeating my question really :)

Comment: @rodrigo: Except a comma would be incorrect where the semicolon is currently.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I am providing my interpretation, together with the additional bit that the break in the semantics would show up in Appendix C, specifically C.2.11, together with the other two changes in the semantics. No mention being done in that section can be used as a hint that the semantics in C++03 are maintained, and C++03 does not have any limitation on changing the values through `operator[]`. As of the question *am I sure?*, yes, I am sure.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's pretty good reasoning actually. Fancy injecting it into your answer? :)

Comment: "I am not a native English speaker" - that's OK, at times I think the authors of the standard aren't either. And no doubt some of the people providing text truly aren't, so I definitely agree that an interpretation within the context of the rest of the standard is more important than a strict letter-of-English-grammar reading.

Comment: BTW, for "are you sure?" I was looking for more than just a "yes"! Your reasoning with Appendix C is good though.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Right, I should have added that *I am sure, but have been proven to be wrong many times* :)

Answer (score 4):

In n3690 (C++14 draft), the wording has been changed to:

> **Returns:** `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.

I believe that this resolves the English ambiguity, and makes clear the intent of the original, ambiguous C++11 passage.