# Is it safe to write to a std::strings buffer directly?

Tags: c++11, stdstring

If I have the following code:

```
std::string hello = "hello world"; 
char* internalBuffer = &hello[0];
```

Is it then safe to write to internalBuffer  up to hello.length()? Or is this UB/implemention defined? Obviously I can write tests and see that this works, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Since `str[i] = 'c'` is well-defined, I would expect your example to be well-defined as well. I'm curious what the answer might be.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring

Comment: @axe Not a duplicate, as this behavior was changed with C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.  No, it's not explicitly allowed by the standard. 
According to my copy of the standard draft from like half a year ago, they do assure that `data()` points at a contiguous array, and that that array be the same as what you receive from operator[]:

```
21.4.7.1 basic_string accessors [string.accessors]
const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
const charT* data() const noexcept;
Returns: A pointer p such that p + i == &operator[](i) for each i in [0,size()].
```

From this one can conclude that operator[] returns a reference to some place within that contiguous array.  They also allow the returned reference from (non-const) operator[] be modified.  
Having a non-const reference to one member of an array I dare to say that we can modify the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant section in the standard is §21.4.5:

> `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const noexcept;`
>
> `reference operator[](size_type pos) noexcept;`
>
> [...]
>
> Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an
>   object of type `T` with value `charT()`; **the referenced value shall not be modified**.

If I understand this correctly, it means that as long as the index given to `operator[]` is smaller than the string's `size`, one is allowed to modify the value. If however, the index is equal to `size` and thus we obtain the `\0` terminating the string, we must not write to this value.

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) uses a slightly different wording here:

> If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value `CharT()` (the null character) is returned.
>   For the first (non-const) version,the behavior is undefined if this character is modified.

I read this such that 'this character' here only refers to the default constructed `CharT`, and not to the reference returned in the other case. But I admit that the wording is a bit confusing here.

Comment: Such a phrase is normally to apply to the whole of "`*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`", but that would not make any sense here.

Comment: ...which is why the text has been changed in later drafts ([according to this answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18078800/743382)).

Answer (score 0):

In practice it is safe, theoretically - no.

C++ standard doesn't force to implement `string` as a sequential character array like it does for the `vector`. I'm not aware of any implementation of `string` where it is not safe, but theoretically there is no guarantee.

http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Comment: Oh, maybe it's changed in the latest standard. Need to check.

Comment: AFAIK yes it changes, it was decided from the fact that it was implemented like that anyway in the different libraries.